# Navigating sharepoint with a treeview

Tags: sharepoint, treeview, navigation

I'm trying to replace the navigation on our sharepoint site with a treeview. It's a large site with up to 4 subsite leves in places. All I need it to do is

- show a consistent structure from page to page
- show only sites and pages

The default sharepoint treeview seems to do neither of these things (doesn't display items from the parent site, includes document libraries but not pages).

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this? We're using the publishing site template throughout if that makes a difference.

I've tried binding the tree to the datasource the quick launch uses but I guess from the error message they expect differently named properties.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using the default property of sharepoint.

But I had also almost the same requirement. I did this task by the following way

1. Store all the links in an XML file.
2. Create a webpart for reading XML file and create menu
3. Open the masterpage using sharepoint designer and comment the lines which render the top navigation and place the new webpart  there
4. Inherit this masterpage in its subsite.

For multi level quick launch the below link will help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/04/26/customizing-the-quick-launch-menu-adding-fly-out-menus-to-sharepoint-navigation.aspx

If you want more help, pls ask me, I can help you

Comment: sorry, we a treeview that reads the hierachy from the site, not a manually updated file.